# How can I make this query work?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subquery

I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101484/looping-over-a-recordset-in-sql) yesterday and for some reason i cant get it to work. I got many good answers but they dont meet the scope of what i need. Basically i need to run a query that will loop through all the customers and grab their Acct_Balance and set it to 0 but before I set it to 0 i need to add an entry with that negative amount to the AR_Transactions table. So for real numbers sake if a customer has -200 in the Acct_Balance field in the customer table then i need to add an entry or 200 to bring the value to 0. Kind of like a line item to 0 it out. And vice verca for if the customer has 200 in the in the Acct_Balance field in the customer table then i need to add an entry or -200 to zero that out as well. I tried a few things. Here is one of the examples i tried.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
INSERT INTO [cresql].[dbo].[AR_Transactions] 
(Trans_ID, DateTime , Dirty, Store_ID, Trans_Type,  Cashier_ID,  CustNum,     Trans_Amount, Prev_Cust_Balance ) 
SELECT  (SELECT MAX(Trans_ID ) + 1 FROM [cresql].[dbo].[AR_Transactions]), DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, Getdate()), 1, 1001, 'C', 100199,     CustNum,     -Acct_Balance,   Acct_Balance 
FROM  [cresql].[dbo].[Customer] 
WHERE Acct_Balance <> 0  
UPDATE [cresql].[dbo].[Customer] SET Acct_Balance = 0 
WHERE Acct_Balance <> 0  
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

but i got this error

```
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 3
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'pkAR_Transactions'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AR_Transactions'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I tried to run the insert statement and all works fine but with this query it fails....Also the pkAR_Transactions primary key is apparantly not non-increment which is why i am doing this hack to get the last entry in that field

Here is my db structure for the two tables..

AR_Transactions table

```
column name type allow null 
Trans_ID bigint Unchecked
DateTime datetime Unchecked
Cashier_ID nvarchar(50) Checked
CustNum nvarchar(12) Unchecked
Trans_Type nvarchar(2) Unchecked
Prev_Cust_Balance money Checked
Prev_Inv_Balance money Checked
Trans_Amount money Unchecked
Payment_Method nvarchar(4) Checked
Payment_Info nvarchar(20) Checked
Description nvarchar(38) Checked
Invoice_Number bigint Unchecked
Store_ID nvarchar(10) Unchecked
Dirty bit Unchecked
Station_ID nvarchar(5) Checked
Payment_Type smallint Checked
```

Customers Table

```
column name type allow null 
CustNum nvarchar(12) Unchecked
First_Name nvarchar(15) Checked
Last_Name nvarchar(15) Unchecked
Company nvarchar(30) Checked
Address_1 nvarchar(30) Checked
Address_2 nvarchar(30) Checked
City nvarchar(20) Checked
State nvarchar(12) Checked
Zip_Code nvarchar(10) Checked
Phone_1 nvarchar(15) Checked
Phone_2 nvarchar(15) Checked
CC_Type nvarchar(5) Checked
CC_Num nvarchar(50) Checked
CC_Exp nvarchar(8) Checked
Discount_Level nvarchar(1) Unchecked
Discount_Percent real Unchecked
Acct_Open_Date datetime Checked
Acct_Close_Date datetime Checked
Acct_Balance money Checked
Acct_Max_Balance money Checked
Bonus_Plan_Member bit Unchecked
Bonus_Points int Checked
Tax_Exempt bit Unchecked
Member_Exp datetime Checked
Dirty bit Unchecked
Phone_3 nvarchar(15) Checked
Phone_4 nvarchar(15) Checked
EMail nvarchar(50) Checked
County nvarchar(30) Checked
Def_SP nvarchar(10) Checked
CreateDate datetime Checked
Referral nvarchar(20) Checked
Birthday datetime Checked
Last_Birthday_Bonus datetime Checked
Last_Visit datetime Checked
Require_PONum bit Unchecked
Max_Charge_NumDays int Checked
Max_Charge_Amount money Checked
License_Num nvarchar(20) Checked
ID_Last_Checked datetime Checked
Next_Start_Date datetime Checked
Checking_AcctNum nvarchar(20) Checked
PrintNotes bit Unchecked
Loyalty_Plan_ID bigint Checked
Tax_Rate_ID int Checked
Bill_To_Name nvarchar(30) Checked
Contact_1 nvarchar(30) Checked
Contact_2 nvarchar(30) Checked
Terms nvarchar(15) Checked
Resale_Num nvarchar(15) Checked
Last_Coupon datetime Checked
Account_Type smallint Checked
ChargeAtCost bit Checked
Disabled bit Checked
ImagePath nvarchar(255) Checked
License_ExpDate datetime Checked
TaxID nvarchar(20) Checked
```

Comment: why are you doing that, update your table and set your primary key to bi incremented by one on each insert

remove it from your insert query and everything will work ok.

Comment: I am not a SQL programmer....i am a mysql and PHP developer...so i really dont know the best way to do this task...I am looking for any help/advice/direction

Comment: possible duplicate of [Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint error SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103016/violation-of-primary-key-constraint-error-sql)

Comment: the concepts from mysql translate fairly easily to tsql

Comment: yes but i cant solve this issue...i am totally mind-boggled

Answer (score 2):

Run this

```
SELECT  
    (SELECT MAX(Trans_ID ) + 1 
     FROM [cresql].[dbo].[AR_Transactions]), 
     DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, Getdate()), 
     1, 
     1001, 
     'C', 
     100199,
     CustNum,
     -Acct_Balance,
     Acct_Balance  
FROM  [cresql].[dbo].[Customer]  
WHERE Acct_Balance <> 0
```

I suspect you will see that all the records got the same trans_id.  Further this hack will always cause problems with race conditions.

So the real question is why isn't it autoincrementing and how can you get the value without causing race conditions? How are other entries to this table getting the value? Is this third party software that you can't change? If there is any way possible to fix this I would do that first.

Since you say you can't change the db, you still need to find out how it reserves new transids so that no one else will try to use the same one. This is critical. Usually they reserve the id by adding it to a separate table of ids and outputting the result of that insert to use in the rest of their queries - if you don't use the same method, you will break things.  In your case you will need to grab the same number of ids as the number of records you are going to insert. Once you have the ids, you  can do the insert and updates.

Comment: I cant change the db structure....I have no access to that and my requirements ask for that i handle the db structure as is

Comment: i ran it and both are 6 so that is obviously my problem...but i have no clue how to fix it without changing the db structure

Comment: Find out from who owns the code how they assign the numbers for other inserts. They may have a function you can use.

Comment: this is a microsoft application...i doubt i will get much help there...is there a way to view the functions that are available

Comment: In management studio for the database look under Programability- Functions

Answer (score 1):

If the answer to any of the questions below are YES do not proceed.

- Is the AR table in use when you are trying to do the update?
- Are you working on the production system to develop the script?

If the answer to any of the questions below are NO do not proceed.

- I am working on the development system
- I have a proven backup from production in case anything goes wrong.

I believe the issue is the method you are currently using to calculate the AR id value.  The code

```
(SELECT MAX(Trans_ID ) + 1 FROM [cresql].[dbo].[AR_Transactions])
```

returns a single value when the script is run.  The single value is inserted for every customer with a non zero balance.  An option you have is to create a cursor for the customer table to retrieve the customer_id value where the balance is not zero.  Use the customer value to in your code to add the row to the AR table and then zero the balance in the customer table.  Go to the next customer.